# How to get the little 'modifier' menu see screenshot

Tags: interface

i just downloaded the Bevel Curve Tools addon. i just wanted to know what the HotKey is for the modifier tab that pops up get whenever i create a new curve. See image below

[image]

Comment: View menu: adjust last operation

Answer (score 2):

That menu that shows the initial parameters appears only for newly created objects (it's kind of a constructor for your object).

Nonetheless, if you just created the object, closed the menu and immediately realized you wanted to change a parameter, you can adjust it by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>: "Redo last". This won't create a new object but recall the construction menu where you can do adjustments.

If you have already moved the object, then this won't work, as the last operation is no longer the object creation.

Comment: Thank you, i was going crazy but its actually just not possible

Comment: 'That menu appears only for newly created objects' - that's incorrect. It appears after various operations as well.

Comment: I meant the initial menu, not any menu, I'll add more detail to the answer